# .htaccess GET query string not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect url from

```
http://localhost/manual/$
```

to

```
http://localhost/manual/index.php?type=post&post=$
```

My file .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /manual/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # Existing File
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # Existing Directory
RewriteRule . /manual/index.php? [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ type=post&post=$1 [L]
```

But nor working whats wrong, help, sorry if duplicate because I still not understand to create htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule in **/manual/.htaccess**  :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /manual/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?type=post&post=$1 [L]
```